# How to add a bindPopup to a OpenStreetMap embedded to a website using <iframe>

Tags: mysql, node.js, openstreetmap

I added a streetmap to the website using only the < iframe > element because the longitude and latitude values are taken from the database. I made a [Table with steetmap embedded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUdYd.png) and taken value of the longitude and latitude from a Mysql database. I was able to add a marker but I think it would be more informative If i could add a bindPopUp if its possible.

The code i used is this:

```
<td style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"><iframe style = "width:100%; height: 100%" src="https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=<%= data.longitude %>%2C<%= data.latitude %>%2C<%= data.longitude %>%2C<%= data.latitude %>&amp;layer=mapnik&amp;marker=<%= data.latitude %>%2C<%= data.longitude %>" style="border: 1px solid black"></iframe><br/><small><a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=<%= data.latitude %>&amp;mlon=<%= data.longitude %>#map=19/<%= data.latitude %>/<%= data.longitude %>">View Larger Map</a></small>
</td>
```

<%= data.longitude %> & <%= data.latitude %> are values taken from the database.

I did some resaerch but i couldn't a way to use a bindPopUp if the streetmap was embedded by only using < iframe >.